# Extract all inherited types / base list of ClassDeclarationSyntax

Tags: c#, roslyn

How can I extract all inherited/implemented types names list

Let's say that I have this hierarchy:

```
public interface ISomething : ISomethingElse
{
}

public class Other<T> : SomethingOther<T>, Other2
{
}

public class Test<T> : Other<T>, ISomething
{
}
```

and now I do have `ClassDeclarationSyntax` for `Test`

How can I then extract whole hierarchy?

```
var msWorkspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();

var solution = await msWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync(pathToSln);
foreach (var project in solution.Projects)
{
    foreach (var document in project.Documents)
    {
        var semanticModel = document.GetSemanticModelAsync().Result;
    }
}

(...)
var root = semanticModel.SyntaxTree.GetRoot(); // and then recurisve walk

if (current is ClassDeclarationSyntax classDec)
{
    if (classDec.BaseList != null)
    {
        if (classDec.BaseList.Types.Any(x => x.ToString().Contains("_SpecificInterface")))
        {
            var inherited = ExtractInheritedTypes(classDec, semanticModel);
        }
    }
}

(...)

// Here are some my messy attempts to extract it
static object ExtractInheritedTypes(ClassDeclarationSyntax classDec, SemanticModel sm)
{
    var symbols = new List<ISymbol>();

    foreach (var entry in classDec.BaseList.Types)
    {
        var q = sm.Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName(entry.Type.ToString());
        var s = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(entry.Type);
        symbols.Add(s);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but I only managed to find "first level" of inheritance - `Other<T>, ISomething`, but no "deeper"

Edit:

For Code test:

```
public class Test : ITest
{

}    
    
public class Test2 : Test
{

}

public interface ITest
{

}
```

and extraction code:

```
var firstType = sm.GetDeclaredSymbol(lastClass);

var base_types = new List<string>();
var queue = new Queue<INamedTypeSymbol>();
queue.Enqueue(firstType as INamedTypeSymbol);

while (queue.Any())
{
    var current = queue.Dequeue();
    var interfaces = (current as INamedTypeSymbol).AllInterfaces;
    var base_type = (current as INamedTypeSymbol).BaseType;

    foreach (var i in interfaces)
    {
        base_types.Add(i.Name);
    }

    base_types.Add(current.Name);

    if (current.BaseType != null && current.BaseType.Name.ToLower() != "object")
        queue.Enqueue(current.BaseType);
}
```

I cannot find interfaces

Here we started from `Test2` type and we're at the second iteration of `while` loop, so at `Test` type

[image]

Comment: You don't want to use syntax trees to do this - switch to the semantic model. You want to get yourself an `INamedTypeSymbol` for the `Test` class (you'll probably have to get an `ISymbol` and then cast it), then you can explore `.BaseType` and `.AllInterfaces`

Comment: Damn, I still didn't manage to find which APIs should I use :(

Comment: What have you tried? Did you manage to get the `INamedTypeSymbol` from the `ClassDeclarationSyntax`? You should just be able to do `semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(classDec)`. Then cast that to an `INamedTypeSymbol`, and look at its `AllInterfaces`and `BaseTypes` properties

Comment: @canton7 Hmm, thank you - I'm a little bit closer, but for some reasons interfaces arent appearing there. I added example code, code using Roslyn and screenshoot

Comment: nvm it works fine, thank you! Please write something as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Use the semantic model for this. If your base types / interfaces exist in different assemblies, they won't have a corresponding syntax tree, but they will be present in the semantic model. The semantic model is also a *lot* easier to use.

You've already got a `SemanticModel` in your code. Query it to get the `ISymbol` for a particular `ClassDeclarationSyntax`:

```
var symbol = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(classDec);
```

This will be an `ISymbol` (which represents any sort of symbol), and you'll want to cast it to an [`INamedTypeSymbol`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.inamedtypesymbol?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.0.1), which represents a type such as a class or struct.

From there, you can query its [`BaseType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.itypesymbol.basetype?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.0.1#microsoft-codeanalysis-itypesymbol-basetype) property to find the base type, and its [`AllInterfaces`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.itypesymbol.allinterfaces?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.0.1#microsoft-codeanalysis-itypesymbol-allinterfaces) property to see which interfaces it implements.